# Cygwin rsync in Windows fails to find cygdrive mountpoints if run from inside a BASH script in Cygwin terminal

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I have this commandline in Cygwin's terminal on Windows to rsync files from Win to Linux:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avh --progress --no-whole-file --partial --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --omit-dir-times --log-file=/home/Stefan-Admin/transfer_d.txt /cygdrive/d/* root@172.16.1.224:/mnt/disc_1/drive_d/. > backup_to_d_drive_log.txt
```

This works perfectly if run by hand in the Cygwin terminal to copy the disc to a remote Ubuntu machine.

However, placing the above in a script in Cygwin terminal, fails...

E. g.

```
set -e
set -x

timestart=$(date)

/usr/bin/rsync -avh --progress --no-whole-file --partial --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --omit-dir-times --log-file=/home/Stefan-Admin/transfer_d.txt /cygdrive/d/* root@172.16.1.224:/mnt/disc_1/drive_d/. > backup_to_d_drive_log.txt
```

in a file with rwx permissions in Cygwin e. g. called, say

```
do_copy.sh
```

causes Cygwin rsync to report it cannot find /cygdrive/d ?

This is what is shown if the script file is run via "bash -f do_copy.sh" in the Cygwin terminal:

```
+ /usr/bin/rsync -avh --progress --no-whole-file --partial --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --omit-dir-times --log-file=/home/Stefan-Admin/transfer_d.txt '/cygdrive/d/*' root@172.16.1.224:/mnt/disc_1/drive_d/.
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/cygdrive/d/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.2.4dev]
```

I note that the rsync source specification, written as

```
/cygdrive/d/*
```

when run in bash in the Cygwin terminal, suddenly becomes

```
'cygdrive/d/*'
```

if run from a .sh script via "bash -f do_copy.sh" in the Cygwin terminal.

/cygdrive/d does exist:

```
$ df -mh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
D:              1.6T  606G  954G  39% /cygdrive/d
$
```

as proven by the fact that if the above rsync command is ran "straight" in Cygwin terminal, it DOES work...

... but if you run the exact same command in a .sh file via

```
$ bash -f do_copy.sh
```

in the Cygwin terminal, rsync suddenly cannot find /cygdrive/d anywhere.

Why is that?

How can it be fixed so that rsync can be run out of a bash script on the Cygwin terminal?

Thanks!

Stefan

Comment: The error message is generated by bash, not by rsync. It just means that there are no non-hidden files in `/cygdrive/d`. You would get the same message if you did a `echo /cygdrive/d/*`. May I suggest thta you remove the _rsync_ tag? Also I would remove the _linux_ tag, because you don't use Linux.

Comment: Hi there! Above suggestions implemented, tags removed as suggested. Thanks for taking the time to reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution to this issue with running rsync inside a Cygwin BASH script, when rsync cannot find

```
/cygdrive/d/*
```

is to change the rsync statement in the BASH script file to reference as rsync source

```
/cygdrive/d/.
```

e. g. the correct, working rsync commandline to rsync from Windows to Linux from a Cygwin bash script is

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avh --progress --no-whole-file --partial --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --omit-dir-times --log-file=/home/Stefan-Admin/transfer_d.txt /cygdrive/d/. root@172.16.1.224:/mnt/disc_1/drive_d/. > backup_to_d_drive_log.txt
```

After removing the wildcard * from my commandline, I can now rsync with no problems from my Windows machine to my Linux machine from a Cygwin bash -script-.

If executing the command by hand in the Cygwin terminal, using

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avh --progress --no-whole-file --partial --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --omit-dir-times --log-file=/home/Stefan-Admin/transfer_d.txt /cygdrive/d/* root@172.16.1.224:/mnt/disc_1/drive_d/. > backup_to_d_drive_log.txt
```

still works, but the "*" -must- be replaced with "." after the "/cygdrive/d/" string if running rsync from inside a Cygwin BASH script.

Hope this helps someone.

Stefan